# Easy way to add line numbers for pseudocode algorithm

Tags: packages, algorithms, line-numbering

I have some pseudocode entered in LaTeX in a very primitive and naive way (not using any of the `algorithm`, `algorithmic` packages).

Is there an easy way to add line numbers to the code, without rewriting them in the format for the packages?

Thanks.

Comment: You could give the `ulineno` package a try...

Comment: This depends on your pseudo-code. Why don't you use one of the standard packages?

Comment: Are you using `verbatim`? Could you elaborate on your "very primitive and naive way"?

Comment: @Werner Yes, essentially verbatim. For example "if" is just written as "if" rather than /If as required in the packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your "very primitive and naive way" is akin to `verbatim`, then the easiest way is to switch to [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb). Instead of using `verbatim`, use `Verbatim` and add the option `numbers=left`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left]
if (x > 2) {
  do something
} else {
  do something else
}
\end{Verbatim}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

If you don't want to add the option `numbers=left` to each `Verbatim`, you can

```
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{Verbatim}{numbers=left}
```

and use `Verbatim` without options.